# next Page stream is not update on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used two pages. and I added `StreamBuilder` in my first page and I passed `snapshot.data` to next Page. but when value change in 2nd-page value is not changing. How to fix it? I can't call `streamBuilder` in both pages because it's meaning two read in `firebase`. Is there any way to create `singleton` for services and access anywhere?

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: db.getData(),
              builder: (context,snapshot){
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: ()=> Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/nextPage',arguments: Arguments(
                        data: snapshot.data
                      )),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InkWell(
  onTap: ()=> Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/nextPage',arguments: Arguments(
  data: snapshot.data
  ),
),
```

When using the above code, a data snapshot is only sent when you `Tap` on the `InkWell`. Meaning unless tapped on the inkwell it will not provide new data to `nextPage`.

To resolve this issue, I would suggest the following:

**In First page**

- Create `ValueNotifier` instance to observe changes in the common reference:

```
  // change Cast to type that you receive from firebase, or you can omit the cast 
 final ValueNotifier<snapshot_data_type> firebaseDataNotifier = ValueNotifier<snapshot_data_type>();
```

- Update the value of `firebaseDataNotifier` when you receive data from firebase:

```
 StreamBuilder(
           stream: db.getData(),
           builder: (context,snapshot){
             firebaseDataNotifier.value = snapshot.data;
             ...
```

- Pass the `firebaseDataNotifier` as `data` for the `nextPage`

**In the next Page**

- Wrap the Next page widgets with `ValueListenable`

```
  ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: valueNotifier,
          builder: (context, firebaseData, child) {
            // return your next page widget here and use firebaseData instead of snapshot.data
        )
```

**Note:** Make sure you keep the `ValueNotifier` instance outside of both widgets so that they can access it without any dependency.